# Sorting a polynomial linked list by degree

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, polynomial-math

I am trying to sort a polynomial stored in a linked list by descending degrees, but this algorithm seems to miss the last node of the linked list, so the last term of the polynomial is always unsorted. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Node prev = mult.poly; //mult.poly is a pointer to the first node of the polynomial linked list 
Node curr = mult.poly.next;

    do{
        if (curr.term.degree < prev.term.degree){ //compare degrees
            int temp2 = curr.term.degree;             
            curr.term.degree = prev.term.degree;       
            prev.term.degree = temp2;                  

            float temp3 = curr.term.coeff;
            curr.term.coeff = prev.term.coeff;
            prev.term.coeff = temp3;

            prev = mult.poly;
            curr = mult.poly.next;
        } 

        prev = prev.next;
        curr = curr.next;
    } while(curr!=null);

    return mult;
}
```

Comment: Is this a programming excercise? Otherwise why not use a standard `List` and `Collection.sort()`?

Comment: It is part of a much larger assignment, so I have to do it this way.

Comment: Why would you ever bubble sort a linked list? Merge sort is much more natural in that context, as well as faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tried to implement a [bubble-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) on a linked-list. Bubble sort runs a loop inside a loop, and you implemented only the inner loop - that's why it won't work.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Node prev = mult.poly; //mult.poly is a pointer to the first node of the polynomial linked list 
    Node curr = mult.poly.next;

    do {
        if (curr.term.degree < prev.term.degree){ //compare degrees
            int temp2 = curr.term.degree;
            curr.term.degree = prev.term.degree;
            prev.term.degree = temp2;

            float temp3 = curr.term.coeff;
            curr.term.coeff = prev.term.coeff;
            prev.term.coeff = temp3;

            prev = mult.poly;
            curr = mult.poly.next;
        }

        prev = prev.next;
        curr = curr.next;
    } while(curr!=null);
}
return mult;
```

**Tip**: to debug bubble-sort run on a list that is sorted in a reverted order, it will make it easier for you to catch bugs in bubble-sort.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I fix the bubble sort and also switch the nodes, or just do one or the other?

Comment: @StevenT just run your `do...while` inside another for-loop that runs number of times which is equal to the length of the list.

Comment: I added :`for(prev = mult.poly; prev.next!=null ; prev = prev.next)` but I am getting a null pointer exception

Comment: You're getting NPE on `curr`. `prev` follows curr. Run the same logic of loop on `curr` and you should be good.

Comment: With `for(curr = mult.poly.next; curr.next!=null ; curr = curr.next)` it says `curr=curr.next` can only be null at that location

Comment: Even using a while loop as you said, I'm still getting a NPE on that line

Comment: @StevenT I can't debug your code without seeing it... use a debugger and see where do you get the NPE (which line). One more thing that I can suggest without seeing the full code is, set the for loop that wraps the code above (not including the return statement) like this: `for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {...` - I'll add it to the answer.